# How to keep streaming if initial client loses connection?

Tags: agora.io, transcoding

I'm working on an app that streams out multiple presenters via the Agora Live Streaming protocol. Everything works great so long as the person who started the live stream stays connected, however if they lose internet, the stream stops, even if other presenters are still online.

Is there a way to tell the live stream to keep going until "stop live streaming" is called (or all presenters are offline)? My code can handle updating the transcoding config (e.g. video layout) when they go offline.

Comment: As an update, if another presenter immediately calls "startLiveStreaming" as soon as the previous "recording manager" is unpublished, the stream will continue, though there is about a 5-second delay, so the final stream/recording does end up skipping slightly. Not the worst, but not ideal either.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple discussions with Agora Support, it appears the answer is no, **if only using the web SDK**, however they are introducing a new server side feature to make this possible.

It's currently in beta, so you'll have to ask Agora Support to enable it for your account, but once you've done so you can create and update an RTMP converter via their server side API instead of relying on the client SDK to manage the stream: https://docs-preprod.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/streaming_restful

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `startLiveStreaming` method using the Agora Web SDK. You can attach event listeners on all hosts to listen for primary host's online status, in case the primary host (the host that calls the start method) goes offline - a secondary host can call the start (and transcode) method.

You can also use Agora RTM to signal this status.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at my comment update above, you'll see I'm doing that, but it still results in a 5-10 second delay in the stream and resulting recording.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to circumvent that unless you build an artificial host using a backend service that manages the RTMP streaming. You can only guarantee an always on client if you're hosting it yourself using a third party cloud service. To build the client you can use something like puppeteer.

Comment: Yeah, that was actually my original fallback plan, until Agora introduced the API based RTMP converter that I just shared as an answer